# Assign several values to one key Pentaho Kettle

Tags: database, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Please help! 
I have two streams (columns), let's say **col_1** and **col_2**.
There are 50 unique rows in **col_1** and 10 unique rows in **col_2**.
I need to assign these 10 unique rows to EVERY row of col_2.

Actually I need to populate every value from col_1 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you are looking for the `JoinRow (cartesian product)` step.